# How to build an Observable from an array and emit items with an interval of 1s?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Say I build an `Observable` from an array like:

```
Rx.Observable.of(["a","b","c"])
```

or

```
Rx.Observable.from(["a","b","c"])
```

Then how can I emit those characters with an interval of 1s?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.

You can map each array item into another observable that is delayed by 1000ms. This would give you an array of observables that are delayed by 1s.

```
[
  Observable.from('a').delay(1000),
  Observable.from('b').delay(1000),
  Observable.from('c').delay(1000)
]
```

Since we have a 2D structure (array of observables), we need to flatten it to access the values for each observable in the array.

One of the flattening patterns we can use is [concatAll](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatall.md). Because we're doing a `map` followed by a `concatAll`, there's a shorthand method - [concatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md) - that does this for us.

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;

const wrapAndDelay = (val) => {
 return Observable
  .from(val)
  .delay(1000);
};

const stream = Observable
 .from([ "a", "b", "c" ])
 .concatMap(wrapAndDelay);

stream.forEach(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Another approach could be to use an [interval](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/interval.md) to emit values each second. The `interval` method by default emits a counter for each interval (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc.) so we can map each of those values into an array entry at that index.

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;

const arr = [ "a", "b", "c" ];

const stream = Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .timeInterval()
  .take(arr.length) // say how many we need so we don't emit forever
  .map(({ value }) => arr[value]);

stream.forEach(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```